# How to route traffic between L2TP/IPSec and WireGuard tunnels?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, l2tp, wireguard

I have a KVM VPS running Ubuntu 18.04 which is simultaneously:

1. L2TP server (xl2tpd + strongswan) with IP `192.168.42.1/24`
2. Wireguard client with IP `192.168.73.3/24` (server's IP is `192.168.73.1/24`)

Both L2TP and Wireguard connections work pretty well separately from each other.

I want to allow to redirect the traffic from L2TP clients to Wireguard server, i.e. `192.168.42.x <===> 192.168.73.1`

Wireguard config on VPS:

```
~# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf 
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <....>
Address = 192.168.73.3/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = <...>
Endpoint = <....>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.73.0/24
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

L2TP server has been set up using [this awesome script](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn). It creates following iptables rules:

```
~# iptables --list-rules
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol none -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i ens3 -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o ens3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.42.0/24 -d 192.168.42.0/24 -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

IP forwarding is obviously enabled

```
~# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Routing table (with 1 L2TP client connected) is:

```
~# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens3
X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ens3
192.168.42.10   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
192.168.73.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wg0
```

*XXX - confidential gateway and external IPs.*

I've tried to add following rules:

```
~# iptables -D FORWARD -j DROP
~# iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o wg0 -j ACCEPT    
~# iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
~# iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

But forwarding `ppp0 <===> wg0` still does not work.

Which iptables rules should I add to allow such kind of forwarding?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add route on the L2TP VPN clients, which tells that packets to `192.168.73.0/24` should be sent via `192.168.42.1`.

Also, you need to add route on Wireguard server, which tells that packets to `192.168.42.0/24` should be sent via `192.168.73.3`.

The issue with your `iptables` command is that you are adding the rules after `-j DROP` rule. This means that those rules are never hit and packaets are dropped.

You should use `-I` to insert the rules first in the chain.

You also need to check Wireguard client firewall configuration.

Comment: thank you to your response!. L2TP clients have 192.168.42.1 as default route (there is another reason for that, nevermind). I've also done `sudo route add -net 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 192.168.73.3 dev wg0` at Wireguard server side. Unfortunately, no success. Wireguard server successfully pings `192.168.73.3`, but not `192.168.42.1`

Comment: Did you verify routing table with `ip route show` after adding the route? I think you need to use `sudo route add -net 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.73.3` syntax to add the route. The `gw` is important here.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I used correct command, but wrote incorrect here.
Correct command was `sudo route add -net 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.73.3 dev wg0`.

Comment: netstat outputs: `192.168.42.0    192.168.73.3    255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 wg0`

Comment: I updated the answer with further suggestions.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions! you are absolutely right about -j DROP` rule. for me was obvious that I have to remove that rule before adding any other one. so I didn't even think that I have to clarify this point. I've also edited original post.